# What is the benefit of MVVM Light Messenger?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Why should I broadcast messages through the Send method of the MessengerInstance to the receiver viewModels subscribed, causing possibilities of memory leaks (as mentioned by the author) and worrying about unregistering and making debugging harder, when I can just create a public method in the viewModel that is a potential receiver and then call this public method from outside as follows:

```
ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MyViewModel1>().InitMyViewModel1();
```

Comment: You shouldn't use ServiceLocator in other viewmodels, see here: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/

By the way if you use messenger version that uses WeakReferences then you shouldn't worry about memory leaks. I am not sure how MVVM light messenger is implemented. After short googling it seems that you don't have to worry about memory leaks.

Comment: I don't find the arguments against using ServiceLocator in other ViewModels very convincing, as it serves it's purpose very well used that way.

Comment: The dependency is hidden. 
a) Testing is much harder.
b) It's quite dangerous because if you want to simply use VM class that has ServiceLocator call inside you'll run into trouble in runtime. If you inject everything with constructor/properties DI you'll know straight away when you start your app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use messenger only when communication between projects with no dependencies,  Okay,Consider. I have projectA  and ProjectB which is independent of each other no dependencies and both has common reference as ProjectC .If ProjectA wants ProjectB Data or Vice Versa then you can use Messenger or any Eventaggregator class to communicate each other Via ProjectC by publishing from A subscribing in B likewise ...